# How to select count from XML clob column?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-optimization

I am trying to select the count of tags in the XML(CLOB) column.

I tried with

```
select regexp_count(diagram, 'userTask id=', 1, 'c') as "User Tasks",
       regexp_count(diagram, 'task id=', 1, 'c') as "Task"
from process_table
```

It works but, I need to get output faster than using regexp_count.

I tried with:

```
select count(xt.task),
count(xt.userTask)
from process_table process
cross join xmltable(
            xmlnamespaces(default 'http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL'),
            '//definitions/process' passing xmltype(process.diagram) 
            columns
            task varchar2(20) path 'task',
            userTask varchar2(60) path 'userTask'
            ) xt
```

But, I am getting an error `ORA-19279: XPTY0004 - XQuery dynamic type mismatch: expected singleton sequence - got multi-item sequence`

Comment: Is using regular expressions against the CLOB faster than extracting the nodes via XMLTable and then counting those? And are you sure you can't get false matches from the content of text nodes happening to include the expressions?

Comment: Yes, false matches are one more reason to use the XMLTable

Comment: OK, so have you tried that approach and it was even slower; or have you been unable to get it to work? If you need help with that then please edit your question to include sample XML and expected output for that, your current best attempt, and what issues/errors you have.

Comment: Be aware, attributes in XML may appear in any order. `<whateverElementuserTask  id=` would also match, `<userTask anotherAtribute="123" id=` would not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. One is to use XMLTable to look for either child node, get the node names, and count how many times each appears:

```
select
  count(case when xt.name = 'userTask' then name end) as userTasks,
  count(case when xt.name = 'task' then name end) as tasks
from process_table process
cross join xmltable(
  xmlnamespaces(default 'http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL'),
  '//definitions/process/(userTask|task)' passing xmltype(process.diagram) 
  columns
    name varchar2(20) path 'name(.)'
) xt
```

Or you could use FLWOR expressions to get the count for both child node types at once:

```
select userTasks, tasks
from process_table process
cross join xmltable(
  xmlnamespaces(default 'http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL'),
  'let $u := count(//definitions/process/userTask)
   let $s := count(//definitions/process/task)
   return <x><u>{$u}</u><s>{$s}</s></x>'
  passing xmltype(process.diagram) 
  columns
    userTasks number path 'u',
    tasks number path 's'
) xt
```

but I'm not sure that would end up any faster than the first option.

Another option is to use separate XMLQuery XPath counts for each node to check:

```
select
  xmlquery('declare default element namespace "http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL";
      count(//definitions/process/userTask)'
    passing xmltype(diagram)
    returning content) as userTasks,
  xmlquery('declare default element namespace "http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL";
      count(//definitions/process/task)'
    passing xmltype(diagram)
    returning content) as tasks
from process_table
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4f6723d985e6d10ffdf22e6f30c74ec5) with a simple made-up XML CLOB that throws the error you see, and those three approaches (including converting the XMLQuery results to numbers).

I'm interested to see what other people come up with too.

---

> XPath counts returns ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error when there are more than 10 rows. When I add where clause works perfectly

> When I add id = some_number, or when 10 rows are displayed it works.

This will error if a processed row has a null `diagram`; but you can exclude those by just adding `where diagram is not null`.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9f265df9a275c0f5d616cfc6d4119036)

Comment: Thanks a lot! XPath counts returns `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error` when there are more than 10 rows. When I add where clause works perfectly

Comment: @Samuel - I'm not sure how; I can't make it throw that error. Is there something different about the CLOB(s) you are filtering out with the `where` clause?

Comment: When I add id = some_number, or when 10 rows are displayed it works. I don't why :(

Comment: D'oh, I wasn't actually using CLOBs... so do you have rows where `diagram` is null? That will then throw that error; but then you can filter on `where diagram is not null`?

Comment: Yes, I have, works perfectly now. 
Why there is an error, when count(null) returns 0?

Comment: It's the XMLType handling, not the count, that's the problem.

Comment: I tried to add the query to Oracle APEX and I got: [SYS.XMLTYPE] for values, query in APEX SQL commands works well

Comment: I guess you mean with the XMLQuery version? If you don't want to convert to numbers (shown in the fiddle) then you can add `.getstringval()`: i.e. `xmlquery(... returning content).getstringval() as tasks`. Converting to numbers, which does an implicit conversion to a string, seems more useful though.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be better to store the XML as `XMLTYPE` rather than `CLOB`. Then you can create a virtual column and you can even create indexes on it. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE PROCESS_TABLE (
    DIAGRAM XMLTYPE,
    TASK_COUNT      INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
        TO_NUMBER(CAST(XMLQUERY('count(/definitions/process/task)' PASSING BY VALUE "DIAGRAM" RETURNING CONTENT) AS VARCHAR2(100)))
    ) VIRTUAL,
    USER_TASK_COUNT INTEGER  GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
        TO_NUMBER(CAST(XMLQUERY('count(/definitions/process/userTask)' PASSING BY VALUE "DIAGRAM" RETURNING CONTENT) AS VARCHAR2(100)))
    ) VIRTUAL
)
XMLTYPE DIAGRAM STORE AS SECUREFILE BINARY XML; 

CREATE INDEX IND_TASK_COUNT ON process_table (TASK_COUNT);
```

Comment: I tested, and after insert XML which has tasks, and userTasks into diagram column, task_count and user_task_count are 0.

Comment: Do you have a sample XML file? The `XMLQUERY()` clause I did just "quick and dirty" Looks like @Alex Poole used correct query, try his one.